# Garbage collection when using Zend_Session_Handler_DbTable

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

I am trying to use Zend_Session_Handler_DbTable to save my session data to the db but as far as i can see, the expired sessions are never deleted from the database.

I can see a cron job running (ubuntu) which deletes the file based sessions but I couldn't find how gc works on sessions which are saving in db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable` class has a garbage collection method called `gc` which is given to PHP via [`session_set_save_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) when you call `Zend_Session::setSaveHandler()`.

The `gc` function should get called periodically based on the php.ini values [`session.gc_probability`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) and `session.gc_divisor`.  Make sure those values are set to something that would result in garbage collection running at some point.

Also make sure you specify the `modifiedColumn` and `lifetimeColumn` options when creating the DbTable save handler because the default `gc` function uses those columns to determine which rows in the session table are old and should be deleted.

Comment: That was a great answer! Thank you very much

Comment: @drew010 , so setting the resources.session.saveHandler.gc_probability = 1
resources.session.saveHandler.gc_divisor = 1000 or something of the sort in application.ini isn't enough? I need to edit it in the php.ini? It appears my garbage collection only worked after editing the php.ini and doesn't listen to the application.ini values i set.